# Using strict mode, but with exceptions

Tags: typescript

I want to use the compiler strict mode (`"strict": true`), but then I get errors for my models which look like this:

```
@Entity
class MyModel {
    @Column()
    public name: string;

    @Column()
    public email: string;

    ...
}
```

The errors I get are:

> Property 'name' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in
>   the constructor.

The values are being assigned by the ORM when an instance of the model is created, and so all fields are indeed populated.
The question is how do I let the compiler know about that?
These are the options I'm aware of:

1. Don't use strict mode: not really an option, I'd like to have it
2. Mark the properties as optional (i.e.: `public name?: string`): Something I'd like to avoid, as the values are always there and then I'd always need to use he non-null assertion operator to avoid the type `string | undefined` (as I'm using strict mode).
3. Use `strictPropertyInitialization` in conjunction with `strict`: the best option I'm aware of, but that too is not good enough as it effects all the classes in my code base, not just the models.

Is there a better way that I'm not aware of?
Maybe I can relax the restrictions only for a specific library or something?
I also thought of having the models in a different project (different `tsconfig.json`) which is more relaxed, and then use the compiled `.js`/`.d.ts` in the main project, but that feels like an overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [definite assignment assertion](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/01/31/announcing-typescript-2-7/#definite-assignment-assertions) `!`, telling the compiler that someone will initialize the fields and it should treat them as initialized in the constructor. This will suppress any errors regarding initialization.

```
@Entity
class MyModel {
    @Column()
    public name!: string;

    @Column()
    public email!: string;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Ha. I wasn't aware of this feature, but I tried it anyway before posting the question. I get this error: `Expecting newline or semicolon`. Looking at it better now, I see that it's an error from the IDE and not the compiler.

Comment: @NitzanTomer it should work, might just be an IDE ghost error, maybe the IDE typescript version is older.

Comment: It works, as the compiler is content, which is what I'm looking for. As for the IDE (webstorm), it uses the ts language service with version `2.7.2`, so it should be fine, yet it's not.  I can live with that for now, and it will probably get resolved sooner or later.